# When you make a glottal stop in English, does the front of your tongue touch the roof of your mouth?

Tags: pronunciation

When you make a glottal stop (or a glottalized t/stop t) in English, does the front of your tongue touch the roof of your mouth? For example, the word "hit".

Comment: A glottal stop doesn't use the tongue at all; it's done entirely by the larynx. And English doesn't have any glottal stop, or any glottalized stops. In normal /t/ pronunciation, most English speakers touch the alveolar gum ridge behind the teeth with the tip of their tongue, not the "roof" (hard palate) of the mouth. In most languages with a /t/ phoneme, the tongue tip touches the incisor teeth from behind, but English /t/ is retracted to the gums behind, and that's a distinctive feature of an English accent in many languages.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think your comment ("English doesn't have any glottal stop, or any glottalized stops") is only accurate as a description of one particular variety of English, not of "English" as a whole. Various phoneticians have talked about the use of glottal or glottalized stops in English accents; e.g. this post on John Wells's phonetic blog: [glottal t in AmE](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/07/jarek-weckwerth-commenting-on-fridays.html)

Comment: There are occasions when some English speakers glottalize some stops -- I have heard someone saying ***Get' out' of here!*** with glottalized final /t/s and distinct pauses between words. But English doesn't have any glottal or glottalized phonemes, although occasionally they can occur allophonically in certain people's speech. Anyway, it seems clear the OP meant "dental", whether they knew the name or not.

Comment: There are glottal stops in Cockney. Or should I say glot - aw stups

Comment: @JohnLawler I think the question is rather whether those who glottalise their syllable-final /t/s still make alveolar contact (i.e., combining the glottal stop with an unreleased alveolar plosive) or whether they use _only_ a glottal stop. The answer is of course that both variations exist, even within the same glottaliser.

Comment: The problem is that many accent coaches and linguists use the term "glottal stop" to describe what is actually an "unreleased T". In GenAm, and the combination of /t/ + schwa sound + /n/ is pronounced as a glottal stop, the rest are either "real" (either aspirated or un-aspirated), flapped or unreleased.

Comment: English doesn't have glottal stops? Uh oh!

Comment: For an interesting discussion of the many and various uses of the glottal stop by speakers of American English, see this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531739/what-is-it-called-when-people-who-speak-with-a-connecticut-accent-cut-off-ts-a. @herisson's comments are particularly interesting.

Answer (score 1):

**Glottal stops - Cockney or London accent**

No, the tongue does not touch the roof of the mouth. It ends up floating in the middle of the mouth. But the shape of the tongue seems to depend on the vowel. If I say ‘butter’ with a glottal stop, my tongue is flat but floating. If I say ‘glottal’ with the stop, my tongue is more curled up at the sides, but floating. There’s a bit of a diphragm push on the ‘t’ of ‘hit’ as well - like a kick.

The glottal stop is rare in English, but it does exist in ‘Cockney’ - a London accent or localised ‘language form’.

Cockneys are people who are ‘born within the sound of Bow bells’ in London. Meaning, within earshot of the sound of the church bells of Bow church, in East London, and Cockney (the language) has a glottal stop on the letter ‘t’ - so for example ‘better’ sounds like ‘be -er’ with the glottal stop in the middle.

The glottal stop is found more widely also, in most people who have a ‘London accent’ or ‘East end’ (of London) accent - all the way down to Brighton - though the home counties people further south of London speak differently.

The tongue does not touch the roof of the mouth (I’m trying it now!)

The ‘Cockney accent’ is often referred to as just ‘Cockney’ in London, and thought of as ‘a language’ by Cockneys, although it is of course, a version of English.

This video shows the glottal stop in Cockney very clearly:

https://youtu.be/_4MJUi03GHM

Glottal stops also show up in Cockney at the start of words beginning with H - as in: ‘ow?’ instead of ‘how?’, and at the end of words ending in T like ‘light’. And also, in other accents including Glaswegian.

https://youtu.be/TtcLrYwyfPs

Here’s a video showing a few aspects of Cockney speech, including the glottal stop.

https://youtu.be/mmum5Pp5Rq4

PS I’m not a cockney, as I was born in Islington, out of earshot of Bow. But my sister is - she was born at Paddington and you can hear Bow bells from there.

Comment: Note that there are other accents which glottalise /t/ and _do_ make contact. Tynesiders and Northumbrians, for instance, tend to combine the two (think _Lewis_ or _Vera_ for media examples). Even in Cockney, I’d say an utterance-final glottalised /t/ is not unlikely to be accompanied by an alveolar closure as well.